# Storing a reference inside a class

Tags: c++, reference, initialization

I want to re-define `[]` operator for a vector. I thought the simplest way to achieve this is to create my own class, say something like this (this is a *simplified* example):

```
class MyVec
{
private:
  std::vector<double> x; // I don't need a copy in here, it could be a reference
public:
  MyVec(const std::vector<double>& y) { x = y; }
  double operator[](int i) { return x[i-1]; }
};
```

Now the problem is that I basically do not need to copy data to `x`, I could store a reference to it, but as far as I know, I cannot use uninitialized references in class. Nonetheless, maybe there is some kind of workaround for this to work without copying the data?

Comment: what about inheritance ?

Comment: What do you mean, "class construction does not allow for this" ?

Comment: "class construction does not allow for this" is a claim of impossibility for what you want readers to implement for you.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to inherit a std class.

Comment: @MartinZhai: Some standard library classes, including `std::stack`, are expressively designed to be inherited from (`std::stack` has a `protected` data member). So clearly the ungoodness of the idea does not cover all cases. In my opinion it covers only a few special cases, that are usually not of any practical importance.

Comment: @MartinZhai  generally yes, but the if you re-implementing only one operator it may not be so bad solution

Comment: @Виталий  What is the purpose to define the operator that already exists?

Comment: It is possible (see answers), but not a good idea, IMHO. What if a the referenced vector gets out of scope, or freed? A pointer is probably better

Comment: @murphy It's same for pointers too. Smart pointers might be better.

Comment: @songyuanyao what do you mean be smart pointers being better in here? Why?

Comment: @Tim The problem with raw pointers and references is that they don't have the ownership of the object, so they can't know when the object gets destroyed and the pointers and references become dangled. But smart pointers do have the ownership of the object, and manage that by themselves.

Comment: @songyuanyao pointers are better, because you can check if they are valid and the user of the code sees it's a pointer and doesn't assume the vector is copied by value. smart pointers are not the drop in solution for such problems. they are relatively heavyweight, have issues when it comes to inheritance etc.

Comment: @murphy How could you check if the pointer is dangled or not?

Comment: @songyuanyao my comment was to broad. what I meant was: You can (at least) check if the pointer is not null, which is more than you can do with a reference.

Comment: @murphy Well I got what you mean. It just doesn't match the case OP showed. Because we don't know when the object pointed to is destroyed, we don't have any chances to set the pointer to nullptr. It just becomes dangled, i.e. still pointing to the memory where the object has gone.

Comment: @songyuanyao yep, but if the user of the class sees a pointer, he (hopefully) is aware that this pointer needs special treatment, so either he will know that it has limited scope or he will allocate and free it. and if he is lucky the compiler sets the freed pointer to zero in the debug version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the implmentation of the constructor like `MyVec(const std::vector<double>& y) { x = y; }`, member `x` will be default constructed and then assigned by `y` in the constructor's body. But reference members can't be default constructed.

So if you declare the member as reference you have to initialize them by [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

> For members that cannot be default-initialized, such as members of reference and const-qualified types, member initializers must be specified.

e.g.

```
class MyVec
{
private:
  const std::vector<double>& x; // it's a reference (to const)
public:
  MyVec(const std::vector<double>& y) : x(y) {}
  double operator[](int i) { return x[i-1]; }
};
```

Note that for this case the member has to be declared as reference to **const**, because the parameter type of the constructor is reference to **const**.

Comment: Both answers are great but this one appeared few seconds earlier, so I'm accepting this one. Thank you both!

Answer (score 3):

> class construction does not allow for this

It does, you just need to use the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). Using it is the **recommended** way of initializing `class` members from the constructor - you should not use the constructor body for that.

```
class MyVec
{
private:
  const std::vector<double>& x; 
public:
  MyVec(const std::vector<double>& y) : x{y} { }
  double operator[](int i) { return x[i-1]; }
};
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Q9KoqIjA2uxaC8qV)

---

Note that if you take a `const&` in the constructor, you need to store a `const&`, otherwise you lose the *`const`-ness* of passed constructor argument.

Comment: It is a little dangerous since the outside vector may be destroyed before `MyVec` object. Any ideas?

Comment: @MartinZhai: not much you can do - just be careful and document the semantics of `MyVec`. C++ doesn't really have a way to guard the user against that situation... Rust's *borrow checker* is one of the selling points of the language and generates a compile-time error in case of the situation you described.

Comment: @MartinZhai: C++ does not support scope-limited ownership, but Rust does. One needs language support for that. Rust provides it.